# I have a problem while dealing to export data from python in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, read.csv

Below I will Provide you the code I used to export files in csv and it is not working.
Please could you help me find the solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXwDY.png)

Comment: Please be kind enough to provide a minimum reproducible code. Images are not helpful. There is no useful information available in the image as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.